# Why MySQL behavior of IS TRUE, IS NOT TRUE, IS FALSE, IS NOT FALSE is different between WHERE and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider two tables:

**table1**

```
id
1
2
3
```

**table2**

```
id, deleted
2, 0
3, 1
```

Suppose I want to get all rows from table1 that have not been marked "deleted" in table2, i.e. row 1 and 2.
Consider the following SQL (in MySQL):

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
WHERE deleted <> 1
```

This SQL obviously returns just row with id = 2.

I can do a perversion like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
WHERE COALESCE(deleted, 0) = 0
```

And then I'll get row 1 and 2.

But I wanted a more elegant way. MySQL has these nice checks for booleans, IS TRUE, IS NOT TRUE, IS FALSE, IS NOT FALSE that take NULL values into account. So consider this:

```
SELECT id, deleted, deleted IS NOT TRUE
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
```

The result:

```
id, deleted, deleted IS NOT TRUE
1, NULL, TRUE
2, 0, TRUE
3, 1, FALSE
```

Looks great, right? now if I just put this into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
WHERE deleted IS NOT TRUE
```

Oh no! I get just row 2 again!

However, if I put the condition into HAVING clause, it starts working:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
HAVING deleted IS NOT TRUE
```

I get row 1 and 2.

Totally baffling. Seems like a bug in MySQL.

Comment: "a perversion like ..." - one of the most common and standard ways of dealing with issues like this. I'd stick with it, just in case you ever have to write a different dialect of SQL.

Comment: you are right, it's common, but since we're married to MySQL, I thought using a more readable and elegant syntax would be better for the team

Comment: Do you get the same result with `where not deleted <=> 1`?

Comment: It's not (hugely) surprising that different clauses have different semantics. I would avoid `WHERE` and `USING` and write the `ON` clause that you mean

Comment: Is the column called "deleted" or "is_deleted"? You're not consistent with your naming

Comment: @Caleth Moving a predicate from `WHERE` to `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...` gives different results.

Comment: @GSerg and the OP is *expecting* the `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...` semantic

Comment: @Sentry thanks, fixed

Comment: @GSerg yes, you are right, ON clause is not suitable, since it processes the table before/during it's joined, not after, like WHERE

Comment: @GSerg `where not deleted <=> 1` actually works! so strange that `deleted IS NOT TRUE` does not....

Comment: This bug was reported way back in 2012: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67732

Comment: I've added your case to the bug log, that HAVING makes the query work as you expect. I also noticed that you can wrap the join in a subquery, and then use WHERE in the outer query. That works as you expect.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the bug link, I guess my last comment was right.
You phrased it well, feels like NULL generated in the join is treated differently from NULL value in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected and as pointed out by @BillKarwin, this is an old 2012 bug in MySQL :(

"WHERE var IS NOT TRUE yields too little" (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67732)

Update: the bug has been fixed in MySQL 8.0.17 (see the comment on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67732 from [11 Nov 2019 9:44] Erlend Dahl)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.is_deleted = 1
                 );
```

Comment: This would work, but a subquery would give a much worse performance and it is even harder  to read than `WHERE COALESCE(deleted, 0) = 0`